# Printing multiple disp functions with one for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

So, I have a series of display functions, ranging from x1 to x7. These all contain both strings and variables like:

`x1 = ['The result of the scalar multiplication of V and U: ',num2str(scalar_uv)];`
`x2 = similar to above but with for example a value on the cross multiplication of the two scalars.`

Instead of printing out each one through:
`disp(x1);`
`disp(x2);`
`disp(x3);`

I thought it would be possible to print them all out through a for loop or perhaps a nested for loop but I just can't figure out how to do it. I preferably don't want straight up solutions (I won't say no to them) but rather some hints or tips of possible.

Comment: I am not able to get that to function properly, instead it prints out all the text first and after that the values which isn't going to look very good. Also it has the ugly C(1,:) = etc which is in the way.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example solution would be to make a cell array and loop through it, or use `celldisp()` to display it. But if you want to print nicely, i.e. formatted specifically, to the command window you can use the `fprintf` function and format in line breaks. For example:

```
for displayValue = {x1, x2, x3, x4}
    fprintf('%s\n', displayValue{1});
end
```

If you want more formatting options, such as precision, or fieldwidth, the formatspec code (`%s` in the example) has many configurations. You can see them on the [fprintf helpdoc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). The `\n` just tells the fprintf function to create a newline when it prints.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating seven different variables (x1...x7), just create a cell array to hold all your strings:

```
x{1} = ['The result of the scalar multiplication of V and U: ',num2str(scalar_uv)];
x{2} = ['Some other statement with a value at the end: ',num2str(somevar)];
```

Now you can write a loop:

```
for iX = 1:length(x)
  disp(x{iX})
end
```

Or use cellfun to display them without a for loop:

```
cellfun(@disp,x)
```

If you really want to keep them named x1...x7, then you can use an eval statement to get your variable names:

```
for iX = 1:7
   disp(eval(['x' num2str(iX)]));
end
```